# Volumetrics and why mine is not working so well

Tags: volumetrics

So I have a light that is shining through some Gobos behind my sword.

Now the problem is the cubes are not really blocking the light enough to provide nice effect. Why would this be ?

I am new to volumetric so I might be missing a key step
[image]

[image]

After correction suggestions

[image]

Comment: It’s not because the cubes aren’t blocking the light enough, they’re completely opaque. It’s either because this is EEVEE and the volumetric resolution is too low, or because the light parameters are off (maybe the radius is too large) so the shadows are fuzzy.

Comment: I agree with @The LabCat and since this is a problem with shadows thrown by light in volumetrics, it would have been nice if you had included screenshots of Eevee's _Volumetrics_ and _Shadows_ settings as well as the light's properties.

Comment: Added a screen shot from eevee @GordonBrinkmann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quality settings for *Volumetrics* and *Volumetric Shadows* are quite low. Especially *Tile Size* and *Samples*. Here is a comparison of your settings on the left and higher quality settings on the right:

[image: quality settings comparison]

This is only for a higher quality of the shadows. One of the reasons the cubes are not blocking enough light is not the fault of the cubes, but the brightness of the environment. Your world background is not very dark, and of course this lightens the volume and the shadowy parts of the scene as well. Here is a comparison between a brighter background and a darker background:

[image: background comparison]

Of course the volume inside the spotlight cone will never look completely dark where it's shadowed by the cubes, because you are looking at the shadows through the surrounding volume that gets light. But one thing that can help increasing the contrast between light and shadow in the volume is the *Anisotropy* setting in the *Volume Scatter* which is kind of giving scattered light a preferred direction (simply spoken). Here a comparison between the default 0.0 value and 0.7 (but never use the maximum/minimum 1 and -1):

[image: anisotropy]

Last but not least - which doesn't matter in your scene since you have *Soft Shadows* disabled - what can make a difference is the *Radius* you set in the *Light Properties*. Your spotlight looks like it has a large radius (the circle around your light), maybe 1 m or 1.5 m, which can mean objects are not getting so much shadow because either the shadow is very soft or the object is even inside the light radius. So if you would have enabled *Soft Shadows*, here is a comparison of the shadows thrown by your light with e.g. 1.5 m radius on the left, and a smaller light with a radius of 0.01 m (like a small light bulb maybe) on the right:

[image: spotlight radius]

Comment: Thank you, Make changes as suggested. My light is / was 5m in diameter